proof strategy for $y^n \le x^n \implies y \le x$
This is one of those exercises where the result to be proved seem so obvious that it makes it difficult (for me) to think about the details of actually proving it.
Given $n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 0$, and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \le x$, show that
$$y^n \le x^n \implies y \le x$$
I am struggling to get started even with a proof strategy.
My thoughts are:

$n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>0$ is the easiest scenario, we don't need to deal with "roots" or cases like $(\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}$ which is not $ \le (\frac{1}{2})^1$.
$x > 0$ again is the easiest scenario, we don't need to deal with any negative numbers at all.


The exercise is 4.4.6.1 from here, where the section introduces the idea of proof by cases where some cases are not possible as they lead to contradictions.

This makes me think of two cases where $y^n \le x^n$ is one of


$y \le x$




$y > x $



Perhaps I could try to show that the second case $x > y$ leads to a contradiction, but that doesn't mean the first case is necessarily true, that too could be false.

UPDATE 2 : my attempted solution, is below, I'd welcome feedback:

I managed to write a Lean proof (software proof assistant), and because it passed without error, I have some assurance the proof is ok.
Here is the solution translated into English:

It is the case that  $x < y ∨ y ≤ x$. This gives us two cases: $x < y$ and $y ≤ x$.

First case: $x < y$



$x < y$ gives us $x^n < y^n$ since $n \ge 1$ and $0 \le x$




$x^n < y^n$ is equivalent to $\neg ( x^n \ge y^n)$




$\neg ( x^n \ge y^n)$ contradicts the hypothesis $x ^ n \ge y ^ n$




so this case does not occur


Second case: $y \ge x$



This matches our proof objective exactly, so no further work is required.




As stated, your claim is false.  Take $x=1$, $y=-2$, $n=2$.  Then $x^2<y^2$ but $x>y$.

Even for positive case you must take into account whether your values ​​are greater or less than one.

One strategy is to prove this by induction. Prove that the implication is true when $n=1$. Then, assuming it’s true when $n=k$, show that it’s true when $n=k+1$.

@Lulu - I edited the post as I had made a typo on the order of $x$ and $y$

Post edit:  The case where $x=0$ is easy so suppose $x>0$.  Then your assumption implies that $\left(\frac yx\right)^n≤1$ so you are down to showing that $z^n≤1\implies z≤1$ or, equivalently, $z>1\implies z^n>1$.

Assume  that $y>x\ge 0.$ Then $y^n>x^n$, a contradiction.

You can also use induction.

An over complicated way can use $x^n-y^n = (x-y)(\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} x^i y^{n-1-i})$ which has the same sign as $x-y$ if $x,y>0$

The function f(x) = x^n is increasing, since f'(x)=nx^(n-1) is positive

I'd added my own attempt at a solution. I'd welcome feedback.

"Even for positive case you must take into account whether your values ​​are greater or less than one"  No, you don't.     There's no claim that $x^k < x^{k+1}$ (which requires $x > 1$ but only that $0\le x\le y \iff x^n \le y^n;x,y>0$ which holds true regardless as to how they compare with $1$.

The easiest way in my opinion is to use the proposition: If $a< b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.  Do you see how that would prove this using a combination of induction?  (If $x^k \le y^k$ then $x^k x\le y^k x \le y^ky$.  And if $x^k\le y^k$ then $0<y < x$ is impossible.) [On second thought: lulu's $[\frac xy]\le 1 \iff [\frac xy]^n \le 1$ might even be easier.]

Note that a proposition is equivalent to its contrapositive. Therefore we only need to prove that $\forall n∈\mathbb N^*,x,y∈\mathbb R,x\geq 0$,
$$
y>x \implies y^n > x^n.
$$
Since $x$ is non-negative and $y>x$, $y$ is non-negative as well. Thus we can just use the multiplication property of inequalities ($a>b \wedge c>d \implies ac > bd$ for $a,b,c,d\geq 0$).

If $y > x$ then $y = x + k$ where $k > 0$. So $y^n = (x + k)^n = x^n + C$ where $C > 0$. Hence $y^n > x^n$. Yes??

@Hudjefa Yes, you can do that, that is a valid proof. (It is easy to show $C>0$ using the binomial theorem.)

Since another answer has addressed the OP's (i.e. original poster's) question, it becomes open season to show an alternative approach.
As a (perhaps) easier approach, if $~f(t) = \log(t) ~: ~t > 0,~$ then $~f'(t) = \dfrac{1}{t} > 0.~$  So, for all of $~\Bbb{R^+},~$ the function $~f'(t) > 0 \implies f(t)~$ is a strictly increasing function.
Therefore, you have that $~0 < a \leq b \implies \log(a) \leq \log(b). ~$ Siimilarly you also have that when $~a,b > 0,~$ that $~\log(a) \leq \log(b) \implies a \leq b.$
Without loss of generality, $~y \neq 0,~$ or else, with $~x~$ assumed positive, the assertion is clearly true.
Similarly, without loss of generality, $~x \neq 0.~$  That is, $~y^n \leq 0 \implies y \leq 0.$
Now, first assume that $~y > 0,~$ so that you have
$$0 < y^n \leq x^n \implies n\log(y) \leq n\log(x) \implies $$
$$\log(y) \leq \log(x) \implies y \leq x.$$
Now assume that $~z < 0,~$ such that $~z = -y.$
If $~n~$ is odd, then, with $~x > 0,~$ you will have that $~z^n < 0 < x^n,~$ and simultaneously, that $~z < 0 < x.$
If $~n~$ is even, then $~z^n = y^n.~$
In that event, the assumption that $~z^n \leq x^n~$ is equivalent to the assumption that $~y^n \leq x^n.$
So, by the analysis in the first part of this answer, when $~n~$ is even:
$$z^n \leq x^n \implies y^n \leq x^n \implies z < 0 < y \leq x.$$
Note
The above exploration of $~z < 0,~$ is actually unnecessary.
That is, if you have the assertion that $~P \implies Q,~$ where $~P~$ and $~Q~$ are each statements, and you are examining a specific case where the statement $~Q~$ is always true, then no further analysis is necessary.
That is, when you are guaranteed that  $~Q~$ is true, then the implication $~P \implies Q~$ must be true.
The above paragraphs analogize to considering $~z < 0,~$ because you are then guaranteed that $~z < 0 < x.$
More explicitly, if $~n = 2, ~z = -10,~$ and $~x = 1,~$ then, for those specific values of $~n, ~z, ~$ and $~x,~$ the following assertion is true:
$$z^n \leq x^n \implies z \leq x.$$

For $y \leq 0$, the problem is trivial since $y \leq x$. Therefore we only need to consider where $y > 0$
If $x = 0$, $y^n \leq x^n$ is false therefore $y^n \leq x^n \Rightarrow y \leq x$
If $x > 0$:
For all $n\geq 0$, we have
$$\begin{align}x^n-y^n&=(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^n x^ky^{n-k} \\\Leftrightarrow x-y &= \frac{x^n-y^n}{\sum_{k=0}^n x^ky^{n-k}}\end{align}$$
Since $\sum_{k=0}^n x^ky^{n-k} > 0$, $x-y$ and $x^n-y^n$ have the same sign, thus $y^n \leq x^n \Rightarrow y \leq x$
